# Insert a value into dict of nested lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.x

Here i want insert a value into dictionary of nested lists.
This is what I'm tried,

```
company_ids = [1,2,3]   
seller_ids = [[0, False, { u'company_id': 4}]]
result = []
for company in company_ids:
    for i in xrange(0, len(seller_ids)):
        seller_ids[i][2]['company_id'] = company
        result.append(seller_ids[i])
print result
```

I'm getting this

> ```
> [[0, False, {u'company_id': 3}],
>  [0, False, {u'company_id': 3}],
>  [0, False, {u'company_id': 3}]]
> ```

But I'm expecting this,

> ```
> [[0, False, {u'company_id': 1}],
>  [0, False, {u'company_id': 2}],
>  [0, False, {u'company_id': 3}]]
> ```

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the entry in seller_ids that you want to change. Like niemmi said, otherwise you manipulate the same entry every time.

```
from copy import deepcopy

company_ids = [1,2,3]   
seller_ids = [[0, False, { u'company_id': 4}]]
result = []
for company in company_ids:
    for i in xrange(0, len(seller_ids)):
        mycopy = deepcopy(seller_ids[i])
        mycopy[2]['company_id'] = company
        result.append(mycopy)

print result
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you change and append the same list `[0, False, { u'company_id': 4}]` every time to `result` so in the end it will contain three references to same list with latest modification.